# In Java, does thread running main HAVE to be the same which does static content initialization?

Tags: java, multithreading, jvm-hotspot

Actually I'm only concerned about HotSpot 7/8/9, but it would be nice to know about others as well.

Am I allowed to do the following and always expect output to be printed:

```
public class Main {
    static final PrintStream MY_THREAD_LOCAL_PS = new MySpecialPS();

    public static void main(String... args) {
        System.setOut(MY_THREAD_LOCAL_PS);
        System.out.println("/Me written!");
    }
}
```

Where MySpecialPS only allows to write from thread, from which its constructor was called (e.g. thread local boolean set to true in constructor).

Answer (score 2):

In general, you can be confident that a class will be initialized, by exactly one thread, before any of its static members is accessed, any of its static methods is invoked, or it is instantiated.  You *cannot*, however, be confident that the first thread to do one of those things will be the thread that initialized the class.

An application's main class is of course a bit special, but as far as I can tell, nothing in the language specification or in the VM specification guarantees that that class will be initialized by the same thread that later invokes its `main()` method, either.  In that sense, it is not safe to assume that a Java program such as you propose would successfully emit any output.

You can, of course, *test* existing VMs with respect to this behavior.  I hypothesize that what you find that way would be consistent and reliable within each VM implementation.  I'd advise you to avoid depending on such unspecified implementation details, however, even after testing.  Whatever you have in mind to do, find another way.

Comment: Actually, this is a property of the *launcher*, not even the JVM. It would be possible to write an alternative launcher exhibiting a different behavior using the same JVM implementation…